# Mysqli num_rows check to slow?

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

i have an c++ program that sending POST of logs to my server and store it on database, the problem is that the checking of duplicates before insert a new row is not working, i think that the program send the POST very fast and there is no delay between the POSTS to the server so the Mysqli can't handle this, is there any solution from server client? maybe locking rows or something?

```
$date = date('Y-m-d', time());
$prep_select_qa = 'SELECT * from `logs` WHERE `guid` = ? AND `error_code` = ? AND `date_create` = ?';
$select_qa = $db->prepare($prep_select_qa);
$select_qa->bind_param('sss', $_POST['guid'], $_POST['error_code'], $date);
$select_qa->execute();
$select_qa->store_result();
$num_rows = $select_qa->num_rows;
if($num_rows == 0)
{
    $prep_insert_qa = 'INSERT INTO `logs` (`type`, `guid`, `sent_by`, `class_and_method`, `api_method`, `error_code`, `error_text`, `date_create`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)';
    $insert_qa = $db->prepare($prep_insert_qa);
    $insert_qa->bind_param('ssssssss', $new, $_POST['guid'], $_POST['sentBy'], $_POST['classAndMethodName'], $_POST['APImethod'], $_POST['ErrorCode'], $_POST['ErrorText'], $date);
    $insert_qa->execute();
    $insert_qa->store_result();

}
```

Comment: Why not use a unique constraint on `guid`, `error_code` and `date_create` and let the database handle duplicates?

Comment: I want to allow multiple rows with the same guid and error_code only if the date is not the same

Comment: @user3519234 . . . That is why Marvin suggests putting the date into the index.

Comment: @GordonLinoff so i need to make something like this? ALTER TABLE logs
ADD UNIQUE KEY `unique_key` (`guid `, `error_code`, `date_created`)

Comment: Yes. To be clear: I am talking about one single constraint covering all three columns, not one constraint for each.

Comment: I'm looking for something that constraint for each, so it could be multiple rows with the same guid and error_code if the date_create is diffrent. @Marvin

Comment: That is exactly what my suggestion would allow, as Gordon Linoff already pointed out. Basically you move your `$num_rows` check to the database layer, which makes your insert operation atomic and removes the need for own locking (simplified).

Answer (score 0):

First, the answer to your question is that you are retrieving all the rows in order to count them.  Presumably, this requires reading all the data in the table and returning some of it (unless you have indexes).  A faster method is to check the value returned by this query:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM `logs`
WHERE `guid` = ? AND `error_code` = ? AND `date_create` = ?';
```

And an even faster method is not to count but to determine if any row exists:

```
SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM `logs`
               WHERE `guid` = ? AND `error_code` = ? AND `date_create` = ?'
              )
```

This will return 1 if the row exists and 0 otherwise.  Both of the above queries and your original query will benefit from having an index on `guid, error_code, date_create`.

In practice, you should follow Marvin's advice and use a unique index.  This means the database does the checking via a unique index rather than the application.  One very important reason is a race condition.  If two users are inserting the same row at the same time, both might execute the `if` statement, find there are no matching rows in the table, and then insert duplicate rows.

Answer (score 0):

The SELECT scheme must be enclosed in a BEGIN...COMMIT transaction and have FOR UPDATE on it.  Otherwise, some other connection can slip in and defeat your check.

Instead, try to do it in a single, atomic, instruction:

Once you have an INDEX that will prevent duplicates...

INSERT IGNORE -- Silently does nothing if it is a dup.

INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE -- Lets you change something as you try to insert a dup.

Also, the INSERT solutions will be faster (which was your original question).